# python queue & multiprocessing queue: how they behave?

Tags: python, queue

This sample code works (I can write something in the file):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

queue = Queue()
def _printer(self, queue):
    queue.put("hello world!!")

def _cmdDisp(self, queue):
    f = file("Cmd.log", "w")
    print >> f, queue.get()
    f.close()
```

instead this other sample not: (errormsg: 'module' object is not callable)

```
import Queue

queue = Queue()
def _printer(self, queue):
    queue.put("hello world!!")

def _cmdDisp(self, queue):
    f = file("Cmd.log", "w")
    print >> f, queue.get()
    f.close()
```

this other sample not (I cannot write something in the file):

```
import Queue

queue = Queue.Queue()
def _printer(self, queue):
    queue.put("hello world!!")

def _cmdDisp(self, queue):
    f = file("Cmd.log", "w")
    print >> f, queue.get()
    f.close()
```

Can someone explain the differences? and the right to do?

Comment: a side note: you can also import like this: "from Queue import Queue" - this way you will be able to call Queue.Queue like you tried the first time - "Queue()"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Queue.Queue

- Was created to work in **concurrent environments** spawned with the `threading` module.
- Each thread shares a reference to the `Queue.Queue` object among them. No copying or serialization of data happens here and all the threads have access to the same data inside the queue.

### multiprocessing.Queue

- Was created to work in **parallel environments** spawned with the `multiprocessing` module.
- Each process gets access to a copy of the `multiprocessing.Queue` object among them. The contents of the queue are copied across the processes via pickle serialization.
  .

Answer (score 76):

For your second example, you already gave the explanation yourself---`Queue` is a module, which cannot be called.

For the third example: I assume that you use `Queue.Queue` together with `multiprocessing`.  A `Queue.Queue` will not be shared between processes.  If the `Queue.Queue` is declared before the processes then each process will receive a copy of it which is then independent of every other process.  Items placed in the `Queue.Queue` by the parent before starting the children will be available to each child.  Items placed in the `Queue.Queue` by the parent after starting the child will only be available to the parent. `Queue.Queue` is made for data interchange between different **threads** inside the same process (using the [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) module). The multiprocessing queues are for data interchange between different Python **processes**. While the API looks similar (it's designed to be that way), the underlying mechanisms are fundamentally different.

- `multiprocessing` queues exchange data by pickling (serializing) objects and sending them through pipes.
- `Queue.Queue` uses a data structure that is shared between threads and locks/mutexes for correct behaviour.

Comment: Due to this behavior a multiprocessing.Queue will yield a copy of what you put in, while a queue.Queue will yield a reference to what you put in.
To me this was completely not clear from the documentation.