# When does multiprocessing's queue.get() return DONE?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm learning Python multiprocessing module and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515944/how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-in-python) example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def reader(queue):
    ## Read from the queue
    while True:
        msg = queue.get()         # Read from the queue and do nothing
        if (msg == 'DONE'):
            break

def writer(count, queue):
    ## Write to the queue
    for ii in xrange(0, count):
        queue.put(ii)             # Write 'count' numbers into the queue
    queue.put('DONE')

if __name__=='__main__':
    for count in [10**4, 10**5, 10**6]:
        queue = Queue()   # reader() reads from queue
                          # writer() writes to queue
        reader_p = Process(target=reader, args=((queue),))
        reader_p.daemon = True
        reader_p.start()        # Launch reader() as a separate python process

        _start = time.time()
        writer(count, queue)    # Send a lot of stuff to reader()
        reader_p.join()         # Wait for the reader to finish
        print "Sending %s numbers to Queue() took %s seconds" % (count, 
            (time.time() - _start))
```

I was wondering when the `queue.get()` will return `DONE` so I've tried following example:

```
#!/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

if __name__=='__main__':
  queue = Queue()

  print "Before 2x put"
  queue.put(10)
  queue.put(20)
  print "After 2x put"

  print "Before 1s get"
  print queue.get()
  print "After 1st get"

  print "Before 2nd get"
  print queue.get()
  print "After 2nd get"

  print "Before 3rd get"
  print queue.get()
  print "After 3rd get"
```

The last message from this script is `Before 3rd get`, after this the script stuck and only way to end it is to terminate it. From this example you can see that `queue.get()` is blocking (the code will not continue until it ends). How is it possible that in the original code `queue.get()` returns `DONE`, when this situation happens?

**EDIT**

In reply to @KemyLand which nicely explained what is going on here, this is the version that did not stuck:

```
#!/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

if __name__=='__main__':
  queue = Queue()

  print "Before 2x put"
  queue.put(10)
  queue.put(20)
  print "After 2x put"

  print "Before 1s get"
  print queue.get()
  print "After 1st get"

  print "Before 2nd get"
  print queue.get()
  print "After 2nd get"

  print "Before 3rd get"
  try:
    print queue.get_nowait()
    print "After 3rd get"
  except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple.

In your first code, the "protocol" that was agreed between `reader` and `writer` was *`writer` sends any amount of data to `reader`, then `writer` sends 'DONE', `reader` receives it and understands that the data transfer is complete.*

In your second code, **there was no agreed protocol between `reader` and `writer`**, because the writer's point of view is "*I send **two** objects and I'm done!*", while the reader's point of view is "*I receive **three** objects and I'm done!".

Because no part of the runtime environment is able to detect whenever a protocol error has occurred, the application simply blocks, waiting for data that will never come. The only one that can detect this situation is the application itself, because it's the only one that knows of the protocol it obeys. For this purposes, you can use `Queue.Queue.get_nowait()` (you **must** `import Queue` (with capital *Q*), as `multiprocessing.Queue` is just an alias for `Queue.Queue`). If uch a function can't extract an object *inmediatedly* from the `Queue`, it'll throw a `Queue.Empty` exception. (Note: this mess with the module's name was fixed in Python 3).

Comment: Oh, such scholar mistake. Didn't realize that writer sends `DONE`. To be honest I did not fully understood what you've been saying about import. I've modified my question to include working solution, can you please check. Thank you very much.

Comment: @WakanTanka: Of course it's correct! Tell us if you have other issues :).

Comment: @KemmyLand, I'm learning multiprocessing module so I've many issues which I will posting ongoing ;) If you are interested please check my profile there are several questions within past 24 hours, and so far nobody pushed me to right direction. Thank you very very much.

Comment: @WakanTanka: I'll go to your profile in a while. This is a great way for me to something useful in an evening :).