# How to accelerate the application of the following for loop and function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, iteration, batch-processing, funcy

I have the following for loop:

```
for j in range(len(list_list_int)):
    arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = foo(bar, list_of_ints[j])
    arr_1[j,:] = arr_1_.data.numpy()
    arr_2[j,:] = arr_2_.data.numpy()
    arr_3[j,:] = arr_3_.data.numpy()
```

I would like to apply `foo` with multiprocessing, mainly because it is taking a lot of time to finish. I tried to do it in batches with [funcy's](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/seqs.html#chunks) chunks method:

```
for j in chunks(1000, list_list_int):
    arr_1_, arr_2_, arr_3_ = foo(bar, list_of_ints[j])
    arr_1[j,:] = arr_1_.data.numpy()
    arr_2[j,:] = arr_2_.data.numpy()
    arr_3[j,:] = arr_3_.data.numpy()
```

However, I am getting `list object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. What is the correct way of applying foo using multiprocessing?

Comment: According to the docs and my own tests, the way you are calling it _should_ work. Not sure why it doesn't, but you can try explicitly specifying a step (if you want default behaviour the step should have the same value as the first argument).

Comment: is there any other alternative for applying the function? @Mark

Comment: from `for j in chunks(1000, list_list_int):`, `j` is not integer, it is sublist of `list_list_int`, So, you need to iterate `j` again.  
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXDmZ.png

Comment: Thanks for the help @KingStone, could you show an example?

Comment: I updated my comment with code screen. But, chunk cannot increase speed. How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515944

Comment: I am getting a type error: list indices must be integers or slices, not list @KingStone

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use multiprocessing for this case? @KingStone

Comment: What's the purpose of these lines inside a for loop? `arr_1[j,:] = arr_1_.data.numpy()` , they don't do anything (the arr_1 variable is overwritten in the next iteration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list_list_int = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for j in chunks(2, list_list_int):
  for i in j:
    avg_, max_, last_ = foo(bar, i)
```

Comment: still the same, type error list indices must be integers not slices. THANKS!

Comment: Please share `list_list_int`?

Comment: both are the same I just change the names

Comment: `list_of_ints` is a nested list of ints

Comment: `list_of_ints` looks like this: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Comment: however, do you think doing batches will speed up `foo` aplication?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have `chunks` installed, but from the docs I suspect it produces (for size 2 chunks, from:

```
alist = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]                                     
j = [[1,2],[3,4]]
j = [[5,6],[7,8]]
```

which would produce an error:

```
In [116]: alist[j]                                                              
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

And if your `foo` can't work with the full list of lists, I don't see how it will work with that list split into chunks.  Apparently it can only work with one sublist at a time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to perform parallel operations on a numpy array, then I would use [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html).

With just a few lines of code, your operation should be able to be easily ran on multiple processes and the highly developed Dask scheduler will balance the load for you. A huge benefit to Dask compared to other parallel libraries like joblib, is that it maintains the native numpy API.

```
import dask.array as da

# Setting up a random array with dimensions 10K rows and 10 columns
# This data is stored distributed across 10 chunks, and the columns are kept together (1_000, 10)
x = da.random.random((10_000, 10), chunks=(1_000, 10))
x = x.persist()  # Allow the entire array to persist in memory to speed up calculation


def foo(x):
    return x / 10


# Using the native numpy function, apply_along_axis, applying foo to each row in the matrix in parallel
result_foo = da.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x)

# View original contents
x[0:10].compute()

# View sample of results
result_foo = result_foo.compute()
result_foo[0:10]
```