# Python: Share queue between completely different processes

Tags: python, queue

I want to use the same log file in multiple processes. But the processes aren't started with multiprocessing, so they have nothing shared.

While googling around, I have realised that I should make a LogHandler which receives the messages through a queue. The LogHandler then is the only process which writes to the file. But the problem is to share the queue with the other processes.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiprocessing queue in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515944/how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-in-python)

Comment: @blues I think not, because there you can pass the queue object when you call the method, but in my case, I somehow have to find and connect to the LogHandler process (which is already running) and get the queue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lock file and each process check its value before reaching the log file.

For example : 
lockfile.txt write "lock: 0"
And first process comes read is it 0 or 1. If it is 0, write 1 and access log file. Other processes will wait until seeing 0 in lock file.

Comment: but what is when two processes want to aquire the lock exactly at the same time? File operations aren't atomic

Comment: In a similar case I used "grep" and "sed" commands of linux, so calling one line linux command can work.

Answer (score 0):

Python has some package such as `fcntl`, `filelock`, which can call the system locking tools. You can refer to [Locking a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python).