# How to run parallelization on multiple files with multiple arguments in python?

Tags: python

I am not familiar with python, but would like to run a function to read and write multiple files in parallel in python. For a minimal example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd

def multiple(input_path, output_path, n):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_path, index_col=0)
    new_df = df.multiply(n)
    new_df.to_csv(output_path)

workers = 6
input_filenames = [f'input_i.csv' for i in range(1,11)]
output_filenames = [f'output_i.csv' for i in range(1,11)]

with Pool(workers) as pool:
    pool.map(multiple, ...)
```

If I am using `for` loop, I can do this like below:

```
for i, input_file in enumerate(input_filenames):
    input_path = input_filenames[i]
    output_path = output_filenames[i]
    multiple(input_path, output_path, 2)
```

How should I convert into `pool.map` to match the index of each input and output filenames and also feed 3 arguments to the function (`input_path`, `output_path`, `n`)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip three lists `input_filenames`/`output_filenames`/`n` to one list, and then you give the function `multiple` and that list to `pool.map`. It will take each element from the list, and a worker will execute `multiple` on it.

```
def multiple(inp_out_n):
    input_path, output_path, n = inp_out_n
    df = pd.read_csv(input_path, index_col=0)
    new_df = df.multiply(n)
    new_df.to_csv(output_path)

workers = 6
input_filenames = [f'input_{i}.csv' for i in range(1,11)]
input_filenames = [f'output_{i}.csv' for i in range(1,11)]
n = 10 * [2]
in_out_n = zip(input_filenames, input_filenames, n)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)
pool.map(multiple, in_out_n)
pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a pool you can create a `Process`, point it to the `multiple` method, and give it the filenames as arguments.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

processes = []
for i, input_file in enumerate(input_filenames):
    input_path = input_filenames[i]
    output_path = output_filenames[i]
    multiple(input_path, output_path, 2)
    process = Process(target=multiple, args=(input_path, output_path, 2,))
    processs.append(process)
    process.start()


for processs in processes:
    p.join()
```

Comment: thanks @jrose. I have two follow-up questions. How do I set how many cores to use using `Process` (I would like to limit cores rather than all available cores)? And what is the purpose of removing one of processes in `processes[-1].start()` or it's just common way to do it?
`

Comment: `processes` is an array, and accessing `[-1]` of an array accesses the last element, which I then call a method of (`start()`). I wrote the code this way to avoid storing the process in a temporary variable but I can see how it is confusing. To set the number of cores you would need to write the code differently - you would need to put all of the input/output files into a multiprocessing Queue and then have each process access the queue to "get new work." See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515944/how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-in-python