# Creating a Queue.Queue object in the constructer of a process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Am I right in saying that the following is wrong:

```
import Queue
import multiprocessing

class P(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, spy):
        super(P, self).__init__()
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put(1)
```

since I am creating the queue in a the main process instead of in the process of type P. What can go wrong if I create the queue in one process and use it in another, as I am doing above? Note that I don't wish to use self.queue between processes, I just made the mistake of creating it in the constructor.

My understanding is that if I wished to use a queue between processes then multiprocessing.Queue should be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not try to use the queue from both processes, the usual queue should work fine. The queue could in some cases leave a copy at each process, but they are not the same.

And yes, you should use multiprocessing.Queue if the queue is to be used by both threads.

[python queue & multiprocessing queue: how they behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925100/python-queue-multiprocessing-queue-how-they-behave)